# How to rename Sticky at top of lists?

Tags: 8

I am using Drupal 8 theme and i am wondering is there any way to change the phrase *Sticky at top of lists* which appears when creating new posts, to something different like *Appear in Search Results* or *Trending?*

[image: screen shot of menu]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a custom Drupal module do something like:

```
function sfusd_scheduler_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id)
{
    // Let's change sticky at top of lists to client preferred verbiage
    $form['sticky']['widget']['value']['#title'] = 'Pinned to top of announcement list';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I found a not so clean way if you're still looking for this.

in the following file: \core\modules\node\src\Entity\Node.php on line 414(for me)

```
$fields['sticky'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('boolean')
  ->setLabel(t('Sticky at top of lists'))
  ->setRevisionable(TRUE)
  ->setTranslatable(TRUE)
  ->setDefaultValue(FALSE)
  ->setDisplayOptions('form', array(
    'type' => 'boolean_checkbox',
    'settings' => array(
      'display_label' => TRUE,
    ),
    'weight' => 16,
  ))
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE);
```

Change the setLabel value and clear your cache, and the text will be changed. if someone has a neater way of doing this please correct my answer.

Since this is in core i would recommend making a text file and adding the line you replaced and give some extra info because with a drupal update you will have to change this again.